# How to change metadata.name in Helm template and keep the old ones?

Tags: kubernetes-helm

Here is a snippet of my chart:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: MyResource
metadata:
  name: myresource-{{ .Release.Revision }}
  labels:
    {{- include "mychart.labels" . | nindent 4 }}
s
```

My intended behavior is every time I run `helm upgrade`. it would create a new `MyResource`, with revision as suffix and the old ones are kept.

However, it turns out the old ones are removed immediately. For example, when `myresource-2` is created, `myresource-1` is removed immediately. Is there a way to change this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

I found out I can use `helm.sh/resource-policy: keep`